# Draw Graph in UIView

Tags: iphone, graph

I have a graph where user can draw the graph using touch gesture, i want the graph drawn to have smooth edges what Function should be used for this ?

Edit : I draw the graph using Touches method of the UIView, I store the traced path in an array, this array will be used in drawRectMethod to draw lines connecting these points, the problem i am facing is if the user moves the finger too quickly i do not get smooth lines they are more like individual lines connected and my requirement is that they should be curved, i tried using Arcs but not getting the angle correctly.

Thanks

Comment: You have provided us too little information to answer you.  How are you drawing the graph?  What do you mean by smooth edges?

Comment: hi Brad, I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) project.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at sencha graphs project to draw using html5